A question on Serre duality on curves
Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over a field $k$. Let $E$ be a vector bundle over $X$ and let $\omega_{X}$ be the canonical line bundle over $X$. When $k=\mathbb{F}_{q}$, using Serre duality on the vector bundle $\text{End}(E)$ we have $|\text{Hom}(E,E)|=q^{\text{an integer}}|\text{Hom}(E,E\otimes\omega_{X})|$.
Does there exist a surjective map from $\text{Hom}(E,E)$ to $\text{Hom}(E,E\otimes\omega_{X})$ (or the other way around) whose fibers are affine spaces?

In Serre dualityfor curves one has $\mathrm{Hom}$ on one side and $\mathrm{Ext}^1$ on the other.

@Sasha Just made an edit.

As Sasha pointed out, your equality is wrong. Take the curve to be projective line and $E=\mathcal{O}$. Then left hand side is one and the right side is zero.

@Mohan In your example, the LHS equals $q$ and the cardinality of the $\text{Hom}$ on RHS is $1$, so the equality seems correct to me.
